# Import/Export JavaScript can't be used

Tags: javascript, laravel, import, export, vite

I'm trying to export & import a JS code and I can not find the right way to do it.

In **horizontalScrollFunction.js** I have

```
export function double(n) {
    return n * 5;
}
```

In **home_page.blade.php** I have

```
<script type="module">
    import { double } from "./public/assets/customFunctions/horizontalScrollFunction.js"

    console.log(double(5));
</script>
```

The error that I get

```
GET http://mylink/public/assets/customFunctions/horizontalScrollFunction.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Also, my main JS file is imported via **VITE**

**@vite('resources/js/appErp.js')**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/js/appErp.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

[image: folders structure]

**Desktop:**

OS: Windows 10

Browser: Chrome Version 103.0.5060.134

Version Laravel: 9.19

Answer (score 0):

According to [export documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export?retiredLocale=id), you forgot to add the * after function in your js file. So your js code should be

```
export function* double(n) {
    return n * 5;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. I got the same error. Or, it is possible to import it directly from my appErp.js file?